# Visibility of contextMenu option in Firefox AddOn extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, contextmenu

I'm writing my first Firefox add-on extension, which primarily works via the right-click context menu on textboxes.

I want to be able to show/hide an individual option based on whether any text is currently selected in the textbox that the user did the right-click event on.

I've been able to get the basics of it working using messages between the content-script and background-script...

```
content.js...
window.oncontextmenu = function(e) {
  if (e && e.target && (e.target.nodeName == "TEXTAREA" || (e.target.nodeName == "INPUT" && e.target.type == "text"))) {
    var selectedText = "";
    if (e.target.selectionStart < e.target.selectionEnd) {
      selectedText = e.target.value.substring(e.target.selectionStart, e.target.selectionEnd);
    }
    browser.runtime.sendMessage({ "action": "additemvisible", "selectedText": selectedText});
  }
};

background.js...
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
  if (message && message.action) {
    if (message.action == "additemvisible") {
      addSelectedText = message.selectedText;
      browser.menus.update("addtextitem", { visible: addSelectedText != "" });
    }
  }
});
```

**The problem** is that the message appears to get through to the background.js script **after** the context menu has been displayed, therefore the visibility of the menu item becomes based on the **previous** state, not the current state.

Is there a better way to make write this, so that contextMenu items are visible based on the current situation?

Comment: When you create your context menu item you can use the `contexts` property to set when the menu item should be shown. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/menus/create) is the documentation for the `browser.menus.create` function and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/menus/ContextType) are the possible values for the `contexts` property.

Comment: Genius, the `selection` context option didn't even occur to me, so simple! Thank you. Although now I have to figure out how to get what is selected through to the background script!

Comment: Actually, I guess I already have that code, so it's all good

Comment: The selection will be sent to the menu item's on click listener. Take a look at the example on this page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Context_menu_items

Comment: Please, please, please put that information as an answer, and I'll accept immediately... you are a star.  It's a classic case of having already looked at all the pages you've linked to, and not actually seeing the information I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set when a context menu item is shown by using the `contexts` property.
In your case, it looks like you're interested in the selected text on a webpage, there is the `selected` context for that (a complete list of contexts can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/menus/ContextType)).

When the menu item is clicked, the selected text will be sent to the menu item's on click listener, here is an example:

```
browser.contextMenus.create({
  id: "log-selection",
  title: "Process Selection",
  contexts: ["selection"],
  onclick: (info, tab) => {
    console.log(info.selectionText);
  }
});
```